# If backendserver is down then How to handle in Reactjs with Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, axios

Current I am using Axios to fetch data from backend , if the backend is down then how to handle it.
Right now if the user directly access somepage in the APP without login, it will show him the page with blank data.
Since the backend is down it will not redirect also to the 403 page.

[image: Page without data , can be accessed without login]

When the backend is Down the user should be redirected to some other page and he should not be able to see any page if he directly tries to access it.

I am using Redux for state Management
React-Router for Routing
Axios for fetching data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Redirect` and privateRoute.
PriveRoute component:

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...props }) {
  const isAuthenticated = true or false;
  return (
    <Route
      render={props =>
        isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
      {...props}
    />
  );
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

and use it in your `BrowserRouter`:

```
<PrivateRoute
    exact
    path='/home'
    component={<Home />}
/>
```

You can check if your backend is up and set state in redux based on it and in `PrivateRoute` chech  this state and if it is not up redirect to `Component` you want like `login`.

Comment: so PrivateRoute is like HOC

Comment: some how, if it was useful for you, up vote and accept my answer is make me happy :)